# Por que no me funciona la excepcion? (Try Catch) en Java

Tags: javascript, java, string, excepciones

No me termina de funcionar la expcecion en este programa, a ver si alguno sabeis por que... Es un programa para comprobar si un año es bisiesto, y estoy intentando que si se introduce un valor no numerico de un mensaje de error.

```
    import javax.swing.*;

public class Bisiesto {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ano_string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce el año: " ); 
        
        try {
        int ano = Integer.parseInt(ano_string);
        if (ano % 4 == 0 && ano % 100 != 0 ) {
            System.out.println("El año " + ano + " es bisiesto.");  
        }
        else if ( ano % 4 == 0 && ano % 100 == 0 && ano % 400 == 0) {
                System.out.println("El año " + ano + " es bisiesto.");
        }
else {
    System.out.println("El año " + ano + " no es bisiesto.");
     }
        
        } 
        catch(Exception error) {
            System.out.println("Introduce un número válido");
        }
        
        
    }
    }
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "aa"
> at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
> at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
> at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
> at Bisiesto.main(Bisiesto.java:7)

Que puede ser??? Gracias!!

Comment: ¿Qué significa que _no funciona la excepción_? Pregunto, porque según veo, si que está funcionando... probablemente entendemos cosas distintas sobre qué es _funcionar_ para una excepción.

Comment: Primeramente, dudo que el código que has puesto se púeda ejecutar porque así como está debe dar errores  de compilación ya la variable "ano" en el "if" siguiente al "try" no está definida. Si declaras la  variable "ano" dentro  del bloque "try" no puedes utilizarla fuera de este, por tal razón, dudo que hayas puesto el código  correcto.

Comment: @jachguate me refiero a que no me imprime en pantalla el mensaje de "Introduce un numero valido" que tengo escrito.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich He editado el programa y lo he metido dentro del "try" y solo si no introduzco un numero pues que salte a la excepcion y haga esa parte del codigo. Pero sigue sin funcionar como debería

Comment: Así como  está  ahora funciona correctamente.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Gracias, ya me está funcionado bien. Dejo el código completo del programa funcionando y terminado en el post principal! Saludos!

Comment: @coding la solución va en la zona de respuestas y no en la pregunta, edita y corrige por favor

Comment: Ah, lo que querías era mostrar el m mensaje en una ventana y no en la consola que es lo hace el System.out

Comment: Aparte de eso, no me estaba funcionando bien el Try Catch. El system.out lo tenía puesto para hacer pruebas, luego lo he puesto con el JOptionPane. @JuanCarlosGuibovich

Comment: Listo.... @BetaM

Answer (score 0):

Programa funcionando y corregido!! Gracias a todos, lo dejo por aquí...

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Bisiesto {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int repetir_programa = 0;
        
  while (repetir_programa == 0) {  
      
        String ano_string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Introduce un año ","¿Bisiesto?",1);
       
        if (ano_string == null) { 
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if (ano_string.charAt(0) == '-') { //Comprueba si es un numero negativo
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se pueden introducir cifras negativas.", "Error",0);
        }
        else {
       
       
        try { 
            
            
        int ano = Integer.parseInt(ano_string);
    
        if (ano % 4 == 0 && ano % 100 != 0 ) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El año " + ano + " es bisiesto.", "¿Bisiesto?", -1);
        }
        else if ( ano % 4 == 0 && ano % 100 == 0 && ano % 400 == 0) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El año " + ano + " es bisiesto.", "¿Bisiesto?", -1);
        }
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El año " + ano + " no es bisiesto.", "¿Bisiesto?", -1);
     }
        
        } 
        catch(Exception error) { 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Introduce un número válido", "Error", 0);
            
        }
        
        }
  }
    }
    }
```